# Sorting messages from two kafka topics into another topic

Tags: sorting, apache-kafka, apache-flink, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have 2 Kafka topics, each with **one partition**.

I want to use a technology like i.e. Kafka Streams, Apache Flink or Spring Kafka to write data into a third topic by joining these two topics based on Kafka timestamp chronology. However, I'm concerned about the issue that might arise during the first run of such a program. For example, if there are 20 million messages in topic A (3 weeks old) and only 1000 messages in topic B (1 day old).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flink you can use [watermark alignment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment) to avoid having to do a lot of buffering of the source with more data.

Kafka Streams will merge the two streams, reading from whichever stream has the lower timestamp -- but on a best-effort basis.